# Does a client can view my TypeScript classes in Angular and change them after deployment?

Tags: angular, typescript, deployment

I work now with Angular 9 on Visual Studio Code.
I have a service that save secret data about the user (like user id).
When I will deploy my project, and start using my project - 
does the client will has an access to change my classes and the data inside them?

Example - I have a service that save the user id:

```
export class LoginService 
{
  userid;
  username;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router)
  {
  }

  // ...
}
```

After deployment, the client will hs an access to change the LoginService properties (userid, username) 
or he will can't do that?
I ask because I want to reuse the service properties for different components,
and if the user have the access to change the properties in the service - it is bad.
Thanks.

Comment: Do your apps involve a remote server? If they don't, I don't know why you worry about your user ruining their own app (they can always decompile it). If they do involve a remote server, why do you care about the client suddenly saying its userid and/or username is something else? Their token will still identify them as their original userid & username.

Comment: I do work with remote server and I store the token in the angular service. I ask because I don't want to check if the token is right via http request everytime the user jump from one component to another...

Comment: But why does it matter? If the user jump to random component, whatever shown to them are either already stored in the app, in which case there's really no security risk since they can read/change it without mucking with login service, or it comes from your server, in which case the token as always already covered the security part.

Comment: I got you! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The client has access to everything that is stored client side, so technically they can change anything, even though that's not that easy since the code is minified.

You can use an authentication guard to protect your routes and redirect the user to the login page if they don't have a valid token. This can be checked once before allowing users to enter private part of the application, you do not have to make a specific http request to check the token on each route change.

Once you've got the token after logging in, it should be sent along every API requests (for instance using a HttpInterceptor) and checked server side. If the token is invalid or expired, throw an error, and from the front catch the error and redirect to the login page